# MongoDB C# create a function that I can pass a type/class name to it as paramater

Tags: c#, mongodb, types, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a function (see below).

It works great for what I need it to do, and I have another one that is almost the exact same thing except for these 2 lines:

```
        var collection = MongoDB.GetCollection<RocketRequest>("RocketRequest");

        var filter = Builders<RocketRequest>.Filter.Eq("RocketRequestId", 4);
```

I want to be able to somehow make the function dynamic so I can pass it the  so I can use this same function for multiple purposes/types and not need to create a new function for every single one.

For the above 2 lines I want to see if it is possible to somehow pass the object  in the collection to the function as a parameter?

Or worst case have a switch statement to check a string  value I passed and say if this, set it to that, else set it to something else.  Problem with doing this is I can not create the variable inside the switch statement, if I try to create it outside the switch I have to do it as an empty object (then set the collection to what I need inside the switch) and I can not get that to work either.

```
       public static int MongoReadData(string[] MongoListOfFieldsToDisplay)
    {
        int CountRecords = 0;

        // create connection TO MongoDB
        MongoClient MongoClientConn = new MongoDatabaseConnection().mongoConn();
        var MongoDB = MongoClientConn.GetDatabase("Viper");
        var collection = MongoDB.GetCollection<RocketRequest>("RocketRequest");

        var filter = Builders<RocketRequest>.Filter.Eq("RocketRequestId", 4);
        //var filter = Builders<RocketRequest>.Filter.Empty;
        var result = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result;

        // do here so it is after the filtering
        CountRecords = Convert.ToInt32(collection.Find(filter).Count());

        return CountRecords;

    }// end MongoReadData
```

Comment: don't understand what do you need. Your function returns count. you don't need foreach loop at all

Comment: I am playing with things still so the what the function does itself is not a problem.  What I need to know is if I can pass something to the function so I can change MongoDB.GetCollection<RocketRequest>("RocketRequest");   To something like:  MongoDB.GetCollection<DynamicPassedToFunction>("DynamicPassedToFunction");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find code that allowed me to pass the class as NEW to make it work to do what I needed. See the new version of the function and the call:

So I call the same function and can use it to query 2 separate collections.

```
MongoReadData_ResponseTEST<RocketResponse>(Mongo_ListOfFieldsToDisplay_RocketResponse, "RocketResponse", "RocketResponseId");
MongoReadData_ResponseTEST<RocketRequest>(Mongo_ListOfFieldsToDisplay_RocketRequest, "RocketRequest", "RocketRequestId");


public static int MongoReadData_ResponseTEST<T>(string[] MongoListOfFieldsToDisplay, string CollectionName, string PKToSearchOn) where T : class, new()
{
    int CountRecords = 0;

    // create connection TO MongoDB
    MongoClient MongoClientConn = new MongoDatabaseConnection().mongoConn();
    var MongoDB = MongoClientConn.GetDatabase("Viper");
    var collection = MongoDB.GetCollection<T>(CollectionName);

    var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(PKToSearchOn, 4);
    //var filter = Builders<RocketRequest>.Filter.Empty;
    var result = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result;

    // do here so it is after the filtering
    CountRecords = Convert.ToInt32(collection.Find(filter).Count());

    return CountRecords;

}// end MongoReadData
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what do you want, you could try this out:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetMongoData<T>(string collectionName, 
                            Expression<Func<T,bool>> filter)
{
    MongoClient MongoClientConn = new MongoDatabaseConnection().mongoConn();
    var MongoDB = MongoClientConn.GetDatabase("Viper");
    var collection = MongoDB.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);

    return collection.Find(filter).ToEnumerable();
}
```

Examples to use:

```
var items=GetMongoData<TestItem1>("test1", t=>t.Points>10);
var items2=GetMongoData<TestItem2>("test2", t=>t.Name.Contains("a"));
```